# macro value assign in sql server pass through

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sas

I'm trying to use the macrovariable in SAS macro as value in the newcolumn
for example :

```
%let macrovariable = value;
```

I would like to have  every single value in newcolumn assign as value
how can do that ? I have used this code below but end up get "&macrovariable" instead of "value".

```
SELECT CAST('&macrovariable.' as char) newcolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes, instead of single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast reply but when I use the double quotes, its asking for column "value"

Comment: I was able to run in native SAS with no problems.  Are you running in Enterprise Guide?  There may be an option to turn off the default prompts.

Comment: I used 9.3. It has asked me for the field or column named "Value" instead of recognize the value as the actaul value.

Comment: How are you calling it.  Are you using PROC SQL?

Comment: ok, I super genius co-worker just help me with this problem :

Comment: SQL server doesn't like the double quotes so the real question is how to resolve a macro variable within single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

So.. here's the answer ( just in case anyone wants to know )

```
SELECT CAST(%str(%')&macrovariable.%str(%') as char) newcolumn
```

This way, it was actually force the macro read it with the single qotation before the pass-through sql server.

Very tricky and very fun - actually.

Comment: A cleaner method is : SELECT CAST(%BQUOTE('&MACROVARIABLE') as char) newcolumn

Answer (score 0):

```
* Add single quotes around mv;
data _null_;
    call symput('mvsq',"'&mv.'");
run;
%put &mvsq; *debug;
...
select &mvsq. ...
```